# Include images in css

Tags: css

Looking at the source of a website today I came across something that surprised me. They had the images included in the css file (see http://static.a.gs-cdn.net/webincludes/css/production-uri.css?20120521.1)

This surprised me, surely loading one large file with all the images embedded would take longer on a modern browser (ie chrome fires off lots a simultaneous requests for the content it needs) and make it harder to debug any css issues. Is that correct and are there any advantages to this approach?

Comment: "are there any advantages to this approach" - the only one I can think of is image obfuscation and even then it doesn't seem like much of a benefit.

Comment: You could Google for `SpriteSheet`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing really wrong with including images in CSS, although it may be more efficient to use CSS sprites.

It makes sense to use CSS sprites for UI elements (but not **content** elements) because it reduces the number of HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a good article](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) detailing a few of the pros and cons of such an approach.

Pros:

> The biggest reason: it saves HTTP Requests. Other than pure document size, this is the #1 factor concerning how fast a page loads. Less = better.

Cons:

> It's hard to maintain site with embedded data URIs for everything. It's easier to just update an image and replace it.
>
> You should only use this in documents that are heavily cached, like your CSS should be. Having a CSS file that is 300k instead of 50k is fine if it saves 6 HTTP requests, but only if that CSS file is cached just as well as those images would be.

Personally, I never use it. It saves on HTTP requests, but bloats your CSS with things that are, in my opinion, not appropriate. For a clean separation of concerns, images should be just that - images.

Plus, you'll have a harder time caching all the resources - if you make one change to your CSS, that's all the image data getting re-downloaded for no reason.

Comment: You should include essential parts of the article in your answer. If the link becomes broken, your answer becomes useless.

Comment: How often does the CSS or the images in question really change?  By the time the user has revisited your site, their browser may have already purged your site from its cache (mobile devices have a very small maximum cache).  Compass (an extension of Sass, a CSS Preprocessor) has a function that generates a string of your image data so you don't have to every time it is updated.  Doesn't seem like there's very many cons left.

Comment: True, there *may* not be any changes over time. It's largely down to personal preference, but I like my CSS to contain nothing but CSS. As Diodeus mentions, sprites are a great solution to cutting down HTTP requests without messing with your CSS - a cleaner approach in my eyes.